Cors issue when deploying application to live server
I am developing a spring boot microservice based application that has the usual API layer that connects to the front-end and dispatches the requests to different microservices. I have developed the security part to have the login into my app and I have set up a CORS filter with it. Locally everything works fine but recently I have deployed the application into a remote server and I can see the front end and the authentications steps (register/login) working fine, however, when doing the post login requests to my api I can see that the prefight requests are working fine but my actual requests fail due to error INVALID CORS REQUEST.




Here is my CORS filter and security filter chain code:
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {        
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
 UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("MY_ALLOWED_ORIGINS"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
        HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,
        HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING,
        HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE,
        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
        HttpHeaders.CONNECTION,
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
        HttpHeaders.HOST,
        HttpHeaders.ORIGIN,
        HttpHeaders.REFERER,
        HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT
    ));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "PUT",
            "PATCH",
            "OPTIONS"
    ));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);

}

 @Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors(withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                    req.requestMatchers(
                                    "/auth/**",
                                    "/v2/api-docs",
                                    "/v3/api-docs",
                                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                    "/swagger-resources",
                                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                                    "/configuration/ui",
                                    "/configuration/security",
                                    "/swagger-ui/**",
                                    "/webjars/**",
                                    "/swagger-ui.html"
                            )
                                .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, 
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }

I have tried allowing everything but still it shows this error, any thoughts on what is the problem?
Thanks!

Please do not post screenshots. Instead, include the relevant parts as text in the question.

From the cors filter posted above I can see the allowed hosts are being hard coded with the string "MY_ALLOWED_ORIGINS" in the line
config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("MY_ALLOWED_ORIGINS"));

I think the above must be changed to a proper host value from where the request is being made.
Also I can see from the spring security documentation that to configure the cors filter we do not need to create a bean of the Cors filter and instead only need to configure the UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource object that needs to be passed to the security filter chain like the example shown below taken from the spring security documentation.
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/api/**")
            .cors((cors) -> cors
                .configurationSource(apiConfigurationSource())
            )
        return http.build();
    }

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource apiConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://api.example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

We can try modifying your code like shown above instead of creating a bean of the cors filter.
And also when enabling debug logging on the DefaultCorsProcessor class spring boot will print in the logs why the cors request was rejected which can give us more information on what is wrong in our request.
To enable debug logs on the corsProcessor class we can do it in the application.yaml file as below
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor: DEBUG

or by providing the debug: true property to enable all debug logs in spring boot.
Hope this helps.
